# How to initialise structure with a field pointing to another field?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Given this struct :

```
typedef struct test {
  char field1[20];
  char *field2;
} test_s
```

How can initialize this kind of structure with a designated initializer, knowing that I want field2 to point to field1 ?

```
test_s test = {.field1[0] = '\0', .field2 = .field1};
```

doesn't work.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: @rsp
Maybe I misread something, but there not a clue that you can do "varName.designator".
In fact, I read nothing usefull for my situation. For what purpose did you link this manual ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of a single-item declaration you can use the name of the variable being declared, because the compiler can take address at any time during initialization:

```
test_s test = {.field1[0] = '\0', .field2 = test.field1};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/c2gYCW)

Comment: And what if I can't know the name of the variable ?

Comment: @Tom's What would be the context for that?

Comment: `#define TEST_CONSTRUCTOR {.field1[0] = '\0', .field2 = .field1}` used like `test_s varname = TEST_CONSTRUCTOR`. I know that i can do `#define TEST_CONSTRUCTOR(varName) {.field1[0] = '\0', .field2 = varName.field1}` but I wonder if not passing the variable name is possible.

Comment: @Tom's I tried a few things, but I can't think of an elegant way around passing variable name to your macro.

Comment: Thanks, it's logic I suppose. I will passing the variable name in my macro and be happy that a solution exist. Thank you !

Comment: @Tom's just my opinion, but `TEST_CONSTRUCTOR` seems misleading. E.g. you couldn't use this with an allocated object. I'd call it `TEST_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: For me : Struct_Constructor : Construct the structure, the purpose is to be able to call Struct_Destructor (if exist) without any problem. Also, this musn't fail (so no operation like malloc, etc etc).
Struct_Destructor : Release malloced memory, close file ... destruct the structure.
Struct_Initialize : Operation that can fail, but necessary to do in order to have an "initialized" structure.

Struct_New : Malloced structure with call to Struct_Constructor.
Struct_Delete : Call Struct_Destructor and free the structure.

That's why I do use Struct_Constructor and not Struct_Initializer

Comment: With this, i can do code like that

`int main(void)
{
  test_s test1 = TEST_CONSTRUCTOR;
  test_s test2 = TEST_CONSTRUCTOR;

  if (!Test_Initialize(&test1, ...)) {
    goto END_FUNCTION;
  }
  if (!Test_Initialize(&test2, ...)) {
    goto END_FUNCTION;
  }

  /* Some code */

  /* GOTO */END_FUNCTION:
  Test_Destructor(&test1);
  Test_Destructor(&test2);
  return (something);
}`